# ServiceStack Basic Authentication Failure

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm trying to utilize the basic authentication of ServiceStack but even after passing the correct credentials, I'm getting the error:

```
[Authenticate: 6/16/2014 4:00:22 AM]: [REQUEST: {UserName:john,Password:test}] 
ServiceStack.HttpError: Invalid BasicAuth credentials at 
ServiceStack.Auth.BasicAuthProvider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession 
session, Authenticate request) at 
ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Authenticate(Authenticate request, String provider, 
IAuthSession session, IAuthProvider oAuthConfig) at 
ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Post(Authenticate request) at 
ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Get(Authenticate request) at lambda_method(Closure , 
Object , Object ) at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object 
instance, TRequest requestDto)
```

The lines of code in my `AppHost.cs` class Configure function is as follows:

```
// Register AuthFeature with custom user session and Basic auth provider
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
() => new AuthUserSession(),
new AuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() }
));

Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

// register storage for user sessions 
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));

var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);

//Add a user for testing purposes
string hash;
string salt;
new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("test", out hash, out salt);
userRep.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth
{
    Id = 1,
    DisplayName = "DisplayName",
    Email = "as@if.com",
    UserName = "john",
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName",
    PasswordHash = hash,
    Salt = salt,
}, "test");
```

And the URL that I'm utilizing for authentication is:

```
http://<domain>:63743/auth?Username=john&Password=test
```

Please let me know what can be the root cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're using Basic Auth correctly, `BasicAuthProvider` in ServiceStack means [HTTP Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication): (i.e. it doesn't mean Simple Auth).

There is BasicAuth support enabled in our ServiceClients, some examples of this is in [AuthTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AuthTests.cs):

The way you send **HTTP Basic Auth** is using the `Authorization` HTTP header, e.g:

```
Authorization: basic {bas64encoded user:pass}
```

Here's example of [sending HTTP Basic Auth with a WebRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RequestFiltersTests.cs#L173):

```
var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AllowedUser + ":" + AllowedPass));
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/secure");
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "basic " + base64Token;
```

If you want to login via a url then you want to register a `CredentialsAuthProvider`, i.e:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new AuthProvider[] { new CredentialsAuthProvider() }
));
```

Which will let you login at the url:

```
/auth/credentials?Username=john&Password=test
```

#### Creating your own Custom Credentials Provider

If you prefer, you can [provide your own Custom Auth Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) you can inherit from `CredentialsAuthProvider` and override `TryAuthenticate` with your own custom implementation, e.g:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, 
        string userName, string password)
    {
        return userName == "john" && password == "test";
    }
}
```

Which you can then register with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new AuthProvider[] { 
        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(),
    }
));
```